# "...that ultimately make your life." Or "...that ultimately makes your life." Which one is right?

Tags: grammaticality, verb-agreement, syntactic-analysis

> Life is too short to regret of not “living your dreams” that
>   ultimately “**make** your life”

Or

> Life is too short to regret of not “living your dreams” that
>   ultimately “**makes** your life”

Which one is right?

The whole sentence is,
"Life is too short to regret of not 'living your dreams' that ultimately 'make your life'."

Please correct where I'm wrong... :) or if it's right?

Would be very grateful..

Comment: You do not provide enough context to allow us to determine whether the subject is singular or plural.  "That" is probably a relative pronoun and would be plural if its antecedent is plural and singular if its antecedent is singular.  In other words, what is the complete sentence under question?

Comment: It depends on how it is used:  *Here is a list of things that ultimately **make** your life better*  OR:  *Marriage is something that ultimately **makes** your life better.*

Comment: Life is too short to regret of not “living your dreams” that ultimately “make your life”. ---- Here is the whole sentence Jim. Let me know what the correct out come should be. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Thanks a lot Micheal.. the whole sentence is,  
Life is too short to regret of not “living your dreams” that ultimately “make your life”.  Can you please correct me? :)

Comment: 1. ‘Regret’ is not usually used with ‘of’. It is quite archaic and obsolete to have the preposition there. “Too short to regret not  doing something” is much more natural. 2. Why are parts of the sentence in quotation marks? Are you quoting anything? They make it very hard to figure out what exactly is going on. 3. ‘Your’ feels wrong here, because of the following relative clause. If you mean what I think you mean, just write: “Life is too short to regret not living the dreams that ultimately make your life”. ‘Dreams’ is plural, therefore it should be ‘make’.

Comment: Thanks Janus for your effort.. to correct the sentence. I really appreciate.. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is not correct at all.  First, remove "of" after regret.  Second, I feel like there is something missing, out of order, or out of context in the sentence.

As to your original question, without knowing what "make" or "makes" is referring to, it would be impossible to determine if "make" or "makes" is correct.  Does it refer to dreams?  Regrets?

My best correction of the sentence would be:

Life is too short to regret not "living your dreams."  Regrets will ultimately "make your life."